# Salesforce Platform Developer II superbadge

Tags: trailhead, certification, platform-developer-2

In the last months Salesforce has changed the way to gain the Salesforce Platform Developer II. Besides the multichoice questions you have to complete four superbadges.

> Effective June 28, 2017, the Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II (PDII) certification will consist of two parts: a proctored multiple-choice exam and four Trailhead Superbadges which replace the Programming Assignment. Similar to the Programming Assignment, superbadges show that you can apply what you've learned to advanced, real-world business requirements covering features, concepts, and scenarios that are essential for a Platform Developer II to know, including Apex programming, data integration and more.

My questions are:

- Two superbadges are already publiced, when will the other two be released?
- How can I communicate that I have completed the four Superbadge to Salesforce?
- Is there an expiration time to do the four superbadges?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**

> As of December 15th 2017, the final two superbadges; [Lightning Component Framework Specialist](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/super_badges/superbadge_lcf) and [Advanced Apex Development](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/super_badges/superbadge_aap) are now available so you can complete your PDII journey and get your hands on your well-deserved Platform Developer II credential!

[image]

---

At this stage the best public information on the remaining two super badges is:

> The other two are in development now with a release date set for later this year [2017].

[Source](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/06/platform-developer-ii-certification.html)

Additional [Source - Changes to the Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II Credential](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Changes-to-Platform-Developer-II):

> **Q: When will the additional superbadges be available?**
> A: The Apex Specialist and Data Integration Specialist superbadges already exist in Trailhead, so you can complete those now. The remaining two superbadges are currently in development and will be available before the end of 2017.
>
> **Q: How do I ensure my Trailhead and Webassessor accounts are linked?**
> A: Today, there is nothing required of you to link your Trailhead and Webassessor accounts. However, stay tuned for instructions in the coming months for linking your accounts.

Now that [Trailhead has merged with Salesforce University](https://twitter.com/SalesforceU/status/892853565785559042) I suspect you won't need to do anything to inform Salesforce except maybe link your existing Trailhead account to what you used for Salesforce U.

Consider linking you certification account to your Trailhead account now. See [Show Trailhead Badges or Salesforce Certifications on Your Community Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232381&type=1)

Otherwise, wait until the official word on what is required to come out.

Comment: What is Salesforce U?

Comment: Salesforce University.

Comment: I have never used Salesforce University. I use Webassessor to register to the exams. I don't understand which is the relation.

Comment: Webassessor is the tool used for the exam bookings and online proctoring. It is more or less considered your Salesforce University certification account. You can already link it with your community profile and Trailhead account. That said, there still isn't an official process for this yet.

Comment: Linking existing Trailhead account to Salesforce U won't work for partners.  We link our certifications to partner community profile and cannot link to trailhead/success community profile as certifications can be linked to only  1 profile.  Still waiting for Salesforce to announce something on this! 
 Have you heard any announcement lately? @DanielBallinger

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy I'll ask around

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy I checked my profile under the https://partners.salesforce.com/. It is the same one I use on Trailhead and it is linked to my Salesforce U account. Do you have a separate account for the Partner Community Profile?

Comment: It is the same but I can connect my certs to either Partner community profile OR success community profile, but not to BOTH profiles.  So my number of certs only show on partner profile, not on success community profile.  Does both of your profiles show the certs? @DanielBallinger

Comment: @DanielBallinger can I complete badges first and write the exam later?

Comment: @cartman I believe so. There is nothing stopping you from completing the super badges before doing the exam.